# javascript fetch() is returning status code 500 with a search from mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, fetch

I am trying to get some elements from MySQL database with javascript `fetch` like so:

```
function fetchPrices(){
    fetch('getPricingPlans.php', {
      method:'POST',
      body: new URLSearchParams('size=' + size)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => viewPrices(res))
        .catch(e => console.error('Error: ' + e))
  }
```

below is `getPricingPlans.php` which is calling another PHP file `livesearch` which is a class who's constructor connects to the database and is the first thing that is called when page is loaded.

```
<?php
require_once('livesearch.php');
$size = $_POST['size'];
$con = new livesearch();
$data = $con->getPrices($size);
echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

next is `getPrices()` from `livesearch.php`:

```
public function getPrices($size){
        $query = "SELECT price FROM PricePlans WHERE size = size";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(["size" => $size]);
        // to put values in an associative array with value mapped to field name
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data;
    }
```

`PricePlans` is my table in the database which contains a column named `price`.

The problem is I am getting the below error when `fetch` is executed:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

some findings:

If I change the `fetch()` to `GET`, and echo a simple string in `getPricingPlans.php` (without going into `livesearch.php`), the error disappears.

Second of all I already got this to work with a different `fetch()` to a different table in the same PHP page with the same format. could it be that having a second call (instance) to livesearch.php is the problem?

Comment: `WHERE size = size`??

Comment: Think that should be `WHERE size = :size`

Comment: The first size is the column name in the table. The second size is the variable name that is populated on execute(). Do you think I am missing something there?

Comment: Change the query to `SELECT price FROM PricePlans WHERE size = :size`

Comment: Typo, corrected.

Comment: `execute()` doesn't need to be changed (the `:` is optional)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just a suggestion  the param should use :param format

```
    $query = "SELECT price FROM PricePlans WHERE size = :size";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([":size" => $size]);
```

Comment: yep it was a typo, it worked!

Comment: If the `:` added to the SQL works, then the question should be closed as a typo!